# Evaluate Cauchy Integral with sinh

Tags: integration

[image: Evaluate Cauchy Integral of sinh(z^2)/(z-i)]

I need to evaluat this Cauchy Integral. Please help - I don't know what do to with the sinh(z^2).

Comment: Yes, but I don't remember how to use that.

Comment: It looks as if you're quoting the end of a sentence rather than giving us the whole sentence.  Could you tell us the whole thing?

Comment: I just re-looked at it. I am supposed to just evaluate it using either Cauchy Integral formula or the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The integral along $\pm 2$ (x axis) and $\pm 2i$ (y axis) is as follows.
\begin{align}
\int f(z) dz &= \int_{-2}^{2} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{2} f(y) dy + \int_{2}^{-2} f(x) dx + \int_{2}^{0} f(y) dy \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{2} f(y) dy
\end{align} 
since the x-integrals cancel. Now since there is only one pole in the square , namely $i$, then the residue is
\begin{align}
\lim_{z \rightarrow i} \left\{ (z-i) \frac{\sinh(z^{2})}{z-i} \right\} = \sinh(-1) = - \sinh(1).
\end{align}
Returning to the integral it is seen that
\begin{align}
2 \int_{0}^{2} \frac{\sinh(y^{2})}{yi-i} \ dy &= -2 \pi i \sinh(1) 
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2} \frac{\sinh(y^{2})}{y-1} \ dy = \pi \sinh(1).
\end{align}

Comment: I just re-looked at it. I am supposed to just evaluate it using either Cauchy Integral formula or the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem.